# How to put data in the map that in the another map?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I faced the difficulties when I try to add the cases number into each date of each country. In my attempt, it will only add the whole list of the record in each date of each country

Below is the output of the `List<List<String>> covidConfirmedList`

```
[Province/State, Country/Region, Lat, Long, 1/22/20, 1/23/20, 1/24/20, 1/25/20, 1/26/20, 1/27/20]
[, Afghanistan, 33.93911, 67.709953, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
[, Angola, -11.2027, 17.8739, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
[, Angeria, -12.3047, 17.8739, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
[, Andora, -13.2087, 17.8739, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
```

I intend to store in the Map<String, Map<LocalDate, List>>. In each date of each country, it should have only store one single record.

Expected Output

```
Afghanistan --> {2020-01-22=[0], 2020-01-23=[0], 2020-01-24=[3], 2020-01-25=[0], 2020-01-26=[0]}
Angola --> {2020-01-22=[0], 2020-01-23=[0], 2020-01-24=[0], 2020-01-25=[0], 2020-01-26=[0]} 
Angeria --> {2020-01-22=[0], 2020-01-23=[0], 2020-01-24=[0], 2020-01-25=[0], 2020-01-26=[0]} 
Andora --> {2020-01-22=[0], 2020-01-23=[0], 2020-01-24=[0], 2020-01-25=[0], 2020-01-26=[0]}
```

My attempt

```
 Map<String, Map<LocalDate, List<Integer>>> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 Map<LocalDate,List<Integer>> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        IntStream //functional for loop to add the date as keys into the map
                .range(0,covidListWithoutCountryDetails.get(0).size())
                .forEach(i->
                        innerMap
                                .put(keys.get(i),new ArrayList<>()
                                )
                );
IntStream  //functional for loop to add the country keys into map 
    .range(0,mapKeys.size())
    .forEach(i->dataMap
    .put(mapKeys.get(i), innerMap));
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using LocalDate as a key - wouldn't it duplicate keys?

Comment: i use country as a key

Comment: `Map<LocalDate,List<Integer>> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();` But over here?

Comment: this is to store the date and the corresponding daily case number